# Login and upload image in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to create login form in the following code.

After successful login , I uploaded the image and submitted. I refreshed the page and I got the following error message:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   index: image Filename: controllers/home.php Line Number: 89 Backtrace:
>   File:
>   C:\softwares\xamp\htdocs\ASOFT\Projects\CG_Pack\application\controllers\home.php
>   Line: 89 Function: _error_handler File:
>   C:\softwares\xamp\htdocs\ASOFT\Projects\CG_Pack\application\controllers\home.php
>   Line: 82 Function: addimage File:
>   C:\softwares\xamp\htdocs\ASOFT\Projects\CG_Pack\index.php Line: 293
>   Function: include_once

What is the problem in this  login  code. Please provide solution for this issue:

Controller:

```
public function login()
    {
           $data=$this->data;
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $password=md5($this->input->post('password'));
    $result=$this->user_model->login($email,$password);
        if(count($result)!==0)
        {   
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$email);
        $seid=$this->session->userdata('user_id');  
        if($seid=='') {
            redirect(site_url());              
        }
        else        {
                $this->load->view('display',$data);
        }

    } else
    {
        redirect('home/index');
    }
    }


public function view()
    {
       $data=$this->data;
       $this->addimage();
 }  


public function addimage()
    {
              $path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                $imgext=strtolower(strrchr($path,'.'));
        $imgname= $this->generateRandomString().$imgext;
         if($path!='')
       {  
       $im= $this->config->item('base_url').'/uploads'.'/'.$imgname;
       $x=$this->do_upload($imgname);
      $data['img']=$im;
      $this->user_model->getimage($data['img']);
      $this->load->view('register_view');
       }
    }
```

Model:

```
    function login($email,$password)
    {
     $this->db->where("email",$email);
  $this->db->where("password",$password);
  $query=$this->db->get("user");
      return $query->result_array();        
 }

    public function getimage($data)
    {
        $var=array('img'=>$data);
        $this->db->insert('login',$var);
        $query = $this->db->get('login');   
        return $query;
    }
```

This is the html code for display.php
View:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Add Image</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2>Upload image</h2>
          <form action="<?=site_url('home/view')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
          <input type="file"  class="upload" name="image" id="file" required value="<?php echo set_value('image'); ?>" />   
    <input type="submit" name="log" value="Submit" />
          </form>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

This is the code for index.php

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Login</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2>Login</h2>
          <form action="<?=site_url('home/login')?>" method="post">
            <div>
              <label>Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
              <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Password</label>
              <input name="password" type="password" id="mypassword" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>"  />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you include the error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Login in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049115/login-in-codeigniter)

Comment: you post same question two times http://stackoverflow.com/q/32049115/2960703

Comment: @DanielV This is the error message      A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: image

Filename: controllers/home.php

Line Number: 89

Backtrace:

File: C:\softwares\xamp\htdocs\ASOFT\Projects\CG_Pack\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 89
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\softwares\xamp\htdocs\ASOFT\Projects\CG_Pack\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 82
Function: addimage

File: C:\softwares\xamp\htdocs\ASOFT\Projects\CG_Pack\index.php
Line: 293
Function: include_once

Comment: @Deena, I don't think the two questions are at all duplicate. In the other question(whose link you have shared), there is no image upload mechanism, while the OP have stated about image upload issue in this question. The two questions share almost same title, but the issues are different.

Comment: maybe you would check if image was uploaded

Comment: Before the image is uploaded, When i refresh the page  it goes to index page.Also  after the successful image upload and  page is  redirected to another success page, i refresh the page  it shows an error  message undefined index image.  This is the  error in my code